# What's the complexity of this loop

Tags: ruby, time-complexity, space-complexity

I'm trying to figure out what's the time complexity of this code that solves the sliding maximum problem

I tried with 2 nested loops but that would be of the complexity O(n*k) and I think that the code listed below is less complex

```rb
  res=[]
  for i in 0..(array.length-k) do 
   res <<  array.slice(i,k).sort[-1]
  end
  return res
```

I want to know what is the complexity of the used default methods (Ruby) and how they affect this loop's complexity. Thanks

Comment: `for` isn't really used in Ruby because there's always a better method for expressing things. Consider: `(array.length - k).times do |i|` as an alternative.

Comment: Not all of us know what the "sliding maximum problem" is. Can you define it (with an edit)? I just looked it up. Given `K`, "Find the maximum element for every K consecutive elements.".

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry I should've explained that in advance

Comment: [3, 3 , 5, 5, 7] should be the sliding maximum (at least that was my intent while making the algo). if not plz let me know how the result should be for your example.

Comment: My apologies. You are right. I misunderstood what was to be returned *after having found a definition of the problem*! 

Comment: I suggest you change `return res` to just `res`, as someone may complain that you can't use `return` from `main` (as `main` is not called from a method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another benchmark, one that shows how relative efficiency changes as `k` (size of each slice) increases.

```
require 'benchmark'

def test(arr, k)
  puts "Testing for k = #{k}"
  Benchmark.bm(11) do |x|
```

```
    x.report("Wonder Boy") {
      res=[]
      for i in 0..(arr.length-k) do
        res << arr.slice(i,k).max
      end
      res
    }
```

```
    x.report("Tadman") { arr.each_cons(k).map(&:max) }
```

```
    x.report("Cary") {
      (k..arr.size-1).each_with_object([arr.first(k).max]) do |i,a|
        mx = a.last
        a << (arr[i-k] < mx ? [mx, arr[i]] : arr[i-k+1, k]).max
      end
    }
```

```
    x.report("Engineer 1") {
      a = arr.dup
      b = a.shift(k)
      max_n = n = b.max
      Enumerator.new do |y|
        y << max_n
        loop do 
          break if a.empty?
          b.<<(a.shift)
          max_n = b.max if b.shift == max_n || b.last > max_n
          y << max_n 
        end
      end.to_a    
    }
```

```
    x.report("Engineer 2") {
      a = arr.dup
      b = a.shift(k)
      max_n = n = b.max
      Enumerator.new do |y|
        y << max_n
        loop do 
          break if a.empty?
          b.<<(a.shift)
          max_n = (b.shift == max_n) ? b.max : [max_n, b.last].max
          y << max_n 
        end
      end.to_a    
    }
  end
end
```

```
arr = 10000.times.map { rand(100) } 
arr.first(4)
  #=> [61, 13, 41, 82]
```

```
test(arr, 3)
Testing for k = 3
                  user     system      total        real
Wonder Boy    0.021185   0.004539   0.025724 (  0.025695)
Tadman        0.004801   0.000000   0.004801 (  0.004809)
Cary          0.004542   0.000000   0.004542 (  0.004568)
Engineer 1    0.003998   0.000000   0.003998 (  0.004005)
Engineer 2    0.003427   0.000000   0.003427 (  0.003438)
```

```
test(arr, 10)
Testing for k = 10
                  user     system      total        real
Wonder Boy    0.003102   0.000000   0.003102 (  0.003105)
Tadman        0.003205   0.000012   0.003217 (  0.003225)
Cary          0.003286   0.000000   0.003286 (  0.003292)
Engineer 1    0.003387   0.000000   0.003387 (  0.003397)
Engineer 2    0.003092   0.000000   0.003092 (  0.003100)
```

```
test(arr, 30)
Testing for k = 30
                  user     system      total        real
Wonder Boy    0.011111   0.000000   0.011111 (  0.011139)
Tadman        0.010568   0.000000   0.010568 (  0.010572)
Cary          0.004292   0.000000   0.004292 (  0.004301)
Engineer 1    0.004197   0.000000   0.004197 (  0.004203)
Engineer 2    0.003759   0.000000   0.003759 (  0.003766)
```

```
test(arr, 100)
Testing for k = 100
                  user     system      total        real
Wonder Boy    0.007409   0.000035   0.007444 (  0.007437)
Tadman        0.005771   0.000914   0.006685 (  0.006703)
Cary          0.002773   0.000000   0.002773 (  0.002782)
Engineer 1    0.003213   0.000000   0.003213 (  0.003222)
Engineer 2    0.003138   0.000005   0.003143 (  0.003150)
```

```
test(arr, 1000)
Testing for k = 1000
                  user     system      total        real
Wonder Boy    0.019694   0.000000   0.019694 (  0.019696)
Tadman        0.031178   0.012383   0.043561 (  0.043571)
Cary          0.005782   0.000000   0.005782 (  0.005788)
Engineer 1    0.002446   0.000000   0.002446 (  0.002431)
Engineer 2    0.002395   0.000000   0.002395 (  0.002396)
```

The most indicative result is almost certainly the one for `k = 100`.

Comment: thank you for polishing the results. I am not that advanced with ruby (at least from syntax perspective). Now I can see each proposition has it's own pros and cons according to the input. Thank you

Comment: To be fair that was not @tadmans proposed solution but rather mine. His is actually far closer to the OP just more rubyesque. Also I would still stand behind mine from a ruby perspective 

Comment: After posted my original benchmark results @engineersmnky found a flaw in my code. After fixing that I re-ran the benchmark and updated my answer above. My code now fares somewhat better than it did previously.

Comment: @CarySwoveland posted a revised and more efficient version seems to out perform the other options for k > 65

Comment: I revised the benchmark by including @engineersmnky's answer ("Engineer 1") and also a variant of that answer ("Engineer 2").

Answer (score 1):

Here an `Enumerator` solution that seems to be the fastest over large data sets (k > ~65)

```
def sliding_max(arr,k)
  a = arr.dup
  b = a.shift(k)
  max_n = n = b.max
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    y << max_n
    loop do 
      break if a.empty?
      b.<<(a.shift)
      max_n = b.max if b.shift == max_n || b.last > max_n
      y << max_n 
    end
  end.to_a    
end
```

Here we only calculate max if the number removed from the array was equal to the max or the value being added is greater than the current maximum.

Comment: If `b.shift < max_n` and `b.last  < max_n` you don't need to calculate `b.max`.  Rather, `max_n = b.shift == max_n ? b.max : [max_n, b.last].max`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland seems to be 6 one, half dozen another as far as speed goes (maybe due to memory allocation for the new `Array`) but you are correct that this would work as well

Answer (score 0):

It often helps to start by reducing the code to the essentials:

```
(array.length-k).times.map |i|
  array.slice(i,k).max
end
```

Where the `sort` can be stripped out here making it linear time for that operation. Normally `sort` is considered *O(log n)*.

This is ultimately *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* unless you can eliminate the inner or outer loop.

If the goal here is to find all of the maximum values in all possible subsets of the array, there's probably an algorithm that can do that.

Comment: there is a lot actually. but, I am looking for the optimal solution which is O(n). I saw someone who used queue in his algorithm but the problem is that he uses a while loops inside a for loop and someone told me that his solution is optimal and I didn't share his opinion. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6o_Wz-UGvc

Comment: Seems `array.each_cons(k).map(&:max)` would do this fairly efficiently

Comment: @engineersmnky oh it works. Can you tell its complexity though?

Comment: @WonderBoy Remember you can find out the complexity of a method like this by testing the time required on random data of varying lengths. You'll get a fairly accurate picture if you run 100 iterations at each of length 1..n.

Answer (score 0):

**How the method works**

I can explain the basic idea of the approach I've used here with an example. Suppose the array were `[1 , 3, 2, 4]` and `k = 3`, and we have already computed `[1, 3, 2].max #=> 3`. Then since `1 < [1, 3, 2].max`, we know that `[3, 2].max == [1, 3, 2].max #=> true`. Therefore, we can calculate `[3, 2, 4].max` by comparing two known values: `[[3, 2].max, 4].max => [3, 4] => 4`. This is a small savings in computational time for `k = 3`, but it would increase with the value of `k`.

**Computational efficiency**

The method below has a (worst case) computational complexity of O(`n*k`) (`n = arr.size`), but randomly-generated arrays should on average require something like `(n-k)*(1+2*(k-1)/k)` operations.

Brute-force methods that compute `a.max` for each `k`-slice `a` of an array, require `(n-k)*k` operations. Therefore, for randomly-generated arrays, the ratio of the number of operations required by my method to that used by brute-force methods is approximately

```
(n-k)*(1+2*(k-1)/k)/(n-k)*k
  #=> (1+2*(k-1)/k)/k
```

For `k = 3`, this ratio is `0.77`, but this method may still be at a disadvantage due to computational overhead. As `k` increases the numerator approaches `3`, so the ratio approaches `3/k`. Therefore, when compared to brute-force methods, my method will pay increasingly large dividends as `k` marches on.

**Code**

```
def sliding_max(arr, k)
  return nil if k > arr.size
  (k..arr.size-1).each_with_object([arr.first(k).max]) do |i,a|
    mx = a.last
    a << (arr[i-k] < mx ? [mx, arr[i]] : arr[i-k+1, k]).max
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
sliding_max([1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0], 3)
  #=> [4, 4, 3, 3, 2]
sliding_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] (fastest)
sliding_max([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 3)
  #=> [7, 6, 5, 4, 3] (slowest)
```

**Explanation**

Let's step through the method for the following arguments.

```
arr = [1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4]
k = 3

return nil if k > arr.size
  #=> return nil if 3 > 7 => false
a = [arr.first(k).max]
  #=> [[1, 4, 2].max] => [4]
enum = (k..arr.size-1).each_with_object(a)
  #=> #<Enumerator: 3..6:each_with_object([4])>
```

The first element is generated and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values.

```
i, a = enum.next
  #=> [3, [4]] 
i #=> 3 
a #=> [4]
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
mx = a.last
  #=> 4
arr[i-k] < mx
  #=> arr[3-3] < mx => 1 < 4 => true
```

so execute

```
b = [mx, arr[i]].max
  #=> [4, arr[3]].max => [4, 3].max => 4
a << b
  #=> [4, 4]
```

The next value is generated by `enum`, passed to the block, the block variables are assigned values and the block calculation is performed.

```
i, a = enum.next
  #=> [4, [4, 4]] 
i #=> 4 
a #=> [4, 4] 
mx = a.last
  #=> 4 
arr[i-k] < mx
  #=> arr[4-3] < 4 => 4 < 4 => false
```

So this time, we must perform the more expensive calculation.

```
b = arr[i-k+1, k].max
  #=> arr[4-3+1, 4].max => [2, 3, 2].max => 3
a << b
  #=> [4, 4, 3]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: I calculated the realtime required by each of the algorithms including yours(using benchmark). Turns out that yours is faster than **array.each_cons(k).map(&:max)** proposed by @tadman but mine came first after I deleted the sort and just put .max instead. Apparently the default methods (like sort) have a great impact on runtime and I need to take them into consideration

Comment: WB, please increase `k` in your testing until my method is fastest. You may want to publish your benchmark in the form of an answer.

Comment: Cary there appears to be a flaw in your algorithm in comparison to the original proposition by the OP [See Here](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/SlidingMaximumProblem)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @engineersmnky. `arr[i-k+1, i]` should have been `arr[i-k+1, k]`, which is what it is now. I checked it at the repl.it link you provided and was rewarded with a blue ribbon. Oh, I just realised I need to change my benchmark as well. Hmmm, that may confirm my earlier puzzlement as to why my algorithm didn't do better in the benchmark. I'll rerun the benchmark now. I'm so excited!

Comment: @CarySwoveland no problem. Updated the repl to reflect benchmarking under your new methodology. With an additional implementation of an enumerator which works better than `each_cons` on larger `k` sets

Comment: @engineersmnky, I think your construction of an enumerator would be of interest to readers. If you will post an answer I'll include it in the benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
require 'benchmark'

def sliding_maximum(k, array)


 time=Benchmark.realtime do
=begin  
             my proposition >
  res=[]
  for i in 0..(array.length-k) do 
   res <<  array.slice(i,k).max
  end
  #return res  
=end     # time => 8.9185999968322e-05


=begin      
              @Cary's proposition >
(k..array.size-1).each_with_object([array.first(k).max]) do |i,a|
    mx = a.last
    a << (array[i-k] < mx ? [mx, array[i]] : array[i-k+1, i]).max
  end
=end    # time => 0.0001353049992758315


=begin     
           @tadman proposition 
 #array.each_cons(k).map(&:max)
=end     time 7.903100049588829e-05
 end 
 p time 

end

sliding_maximum(3, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

This is the code where I tried to calculate the realtime execution of each proposition including mine. Feel free change the passed array or K to see the execution difference. For me, I see that @tadman proposition(the third one) is faster for larger arrays.

Comment: I posted another benchmark, both for my stated reason and because I wanted to show you how these are generally written. btw, a more Ruby-like way to write your method is `(array.length-k+1).times.with_object([])  { |i,res| res <<  array.slice(i,k).max }`. See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). As you become more familiar with Ruby you'll be using that method all the time. Oh, one other thing: this is the last time you will use `for`.